# Preprocessor macro in Android.mk is ignored, but works in Application.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, makefile, preprocessor

I created an Android project using jni. Now I want to use preprocessor macros to distinguish between the lite and the full version. It should look like this:

```
#ifdef LITE
    auto label = LabelTTF::create("Hello Cocos2dx Lite", "Arial", 24);
#else
    auto label = LabelTTF::create("Hello Cocos2dx Full", "Arial", 24);
#endif
```

For this I defined a variable in APP_CPPFLAGS within Android.mk like this:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DLITE
```

Unfortunately the app completely ignores it and I still see the label "Hello Cocos2dx Full".
However the same line works when I put it in the Application.mk.

- Why is that?
- How can I define the variable, so that I can have two different makefiles for the full and lite version?

Answer (score 8):

`APP_CPPFLAGS` and all other **APP_** make variables should be set in **Application.mk**. For changes *per module*, use `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` or `LOCAL_CFLAGS`

Comment: I tried that, but LOCAL_CPPFLAGS has no effect at all :(
And yes, I am sure, that I am working in the correct Android.mk file. I see the warnings in the console, that I added to check that.

Comment: What about `LOCAL_CFLAGS`?

Answer (score 2):

The position of the definition within the Android.mk file was wrong.
I need to define it before defining `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`, but of course after `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` then it works.

Comment: You are right. in addition, put the #define variables in LOCAL_CFLAGS.
Its working like sharm

Comment: With the switch -D<var name>